# Why Does Manually Interacting With Safari Tabs Bring my MacBook to a Halt?

Tags: macbook-pro, safari

I have been tolerating a strange Safari issue for a long time which I cannot be unique in experiencing.

I have noticed that, when opening a new tab or closing an existing tab, Safari freezes for a few seconds; commonly even triggering the spinning beach ball. Interestingly this only happens when interacting with the mouse: using Cmd+T and Cmd+W works pretty smoothly.

For context, I tend to have 2-3 safari windows open, with 50+ tabs in each, most of which are inactive. Is there anything I can do to understand and/or resolve this? (I have tried the tip of changing the default tab page to blank, which did not seem to help).

Updated with screenshots of RAM / CPU usage:

[image]

[image]

Updated: I quit Safari and then re-opened using "History > Reopen All Windows from Last Session" which seemed to help (temporarily). Over time, the lag issue reappears. Therefore it must be some issue from having tabs open for a long time which is gradually causing some slowdown - perhaps a small memory leak somewhere - but I can't understand how this is not seen in the memory usage.

Comment: Look at Activity Monitor. Set the View menu to All Processes  & post pictures of the CPU & Memory sections [the whole window], sorted by largest RAM/CPU to the top.  Best guess is you're hammering the memory & therefore swap file.

Comment: Thanks - just updated with screenshots. Swap file refers ti using the SSD as a RAM alternative right? I didn't know this was a thing on the older MBPs (2016), and also surprising, since to me it reads like only 11.78 out of 16GB is used and "memory pressure" (whatever that means) is low/green.

Comment: It doesn't really look *too* busy. How long has the machine been running, since last reboot? You can get the info from Terminal if you're not sure, just type `uptime`. I tend to find that, even though I have 64GB RAM, things tend to get 'sticker' after a few weeks even if swap is barely touched. I find this far more prevalent on a new M1 iMac with only 16GB RAM & it really needs rebooting every couple of weeks or so to keep it happy.

Comment: & yes, Swap is where memory is moved temporarily to your boot drive to alleviate memory pressure. The Mac's pretty good at doing that, but it can still slow after time. A late thought… how full is the drive?

Comment: I don't think it feels swap-related, because the effect is only observed when using the mouse to open/close new tabs; using keyboard shortcuts works fine. The MacBook has a 512GB SSD of which about 200GB is used.

Comment: It still 'feels' swap-related. You didn't answer my other questions/suggestions.